# list of appendices VS list of algorithm (loa)

Tags: table-of-contents

My list of appendices is conflicting with my list of algorithms because both use loa. Anyone would know the solution?

Comment: Well, without seeing any line of code this is difficult to say

Comment: Yes. Use "loa" and "whatever", not "loa" and "loa" (guessing that you use some like ` \newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}` and `\newfloat{whatever}{tpb}{loa}`, otherwise I must change my crystall ball or you must explain better your problem, showing us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)).