# How to add a list of appendices and algorithms without conflicting

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, appendices

I am working on my thesis and having trouble adding a list of appendices as well as a list of algorithms. My question is very similar to the this one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472287/list-of-appendices-vs-list-of-algorithm-loa) but I will provide a [MWE example](https://github.com/JeremyBYU/thesis-umich) of the issue and some code snippets.  I am using a latex class file ([thesis-umich.cls](https://github.com/JeremyBYU/thesis-umich/blob/master/thesis-umich.cls)) that I believe conforms to my thesis standards.

The issue is that the appendices and algorithms seem to be picked up as belonging to the same group and will be commingled in the table of contents. An example here:
[image: appendix and algorithm comingled]

I think the basic issue is that custom code to make a list of appendices and algorithms both use

```
  \@starttoc{loa}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi %
```

to add to the table of contents ([Line 867 and 895 in thesis-umich.cls](https://github.com/JeremyBYU/thesis-umich/blob/master/thesis-umich.cls#L843-L897)). I believe the `\starttoc{loa}` is the same for both of them and causes conflicts. These linked custom commands will only be called if `\showlistofappendices` or `\showlistofalgorithms` is set in the main `thesis-sample.tex` file. For example if I replace `\showlistofappendices` to `\hidelistofappendices` and remove the appendix in the `thesis-sample.tex`, the table of contents is correctly filled out with algorithm toc, no conflicts.

Basically I'm wondering if there is some way make `\@starttoc{...}` work for both appendices and algorithms without conflict.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do not have the same file extension (loa) for the appendices and algorithms lists. Call one, say `lap` and the other `lal` for example.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried as suggested but it is till not working as expected. The List of Appendices is now working, but no algorithms are showing up in List of Algorithms. Here is the update to changes: https://github.com/JeremyBYU/thesis-umich/commit/79183ad47c1b9ecbd2ddd23df82a26d1b1a7ff58  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay I think I got it working now. I have to keep the `loa` for algorithms but only changed the list of appendices to `lap`. Should be updated and working here: https://github.com/JeremyBYU/thesis-umich

Comment: @JeremyCastagno Thanks! Your solution works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I took Peter Wilsons advice and modified the "file extension" for the appendices list. The appendices is now:

```
\@starttoc{lap}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi %
```

and does not conflict with the list of algorithms. Note that I could not get the algorithms to generate unless I continued to use `\@starttoc{loa}`, I could not rename them to `lal` as suggested.

Here is the updated github repository where you can track these successful changes and effects: https://github.com/JeremyBYU/thesis-umich

Answer (score 0):

I just changed all `loa` to `lop` or any other name in the cls file, to avoid conflicting with "list of algorithm" that already uses `loa` name. After changing like this, the appendix list worked.